# Страница не проходит Validator W3C. Ошибка разбора

Tags: html, css, валидация

Ломаю голову, не могу понять где ошибка.

https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fyug-avto.ru%2Fbuy-car%2Fused&profile=css3svg&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=ru

При этом с основной страницей сайта все ок: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fyug-avto.ru%2F&profile=css3svg&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=ru

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вручную частями код проверяйте и увидите где ошибка

Comment: Все эти валидаторы сами себя без ошибок и предупреждений не пропускают :)